# apply function on all subsets of dataframe

Tags: r, subset, apply

how can i normalize the values of Sepal.Length by Species?

```
    iris
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
...

# i have to divide by 
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, max)
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
       5.8        7.0        7.9
```

in other words i want to divide all values where `Species=="setosa"` by 5.8 and so on
finally i want to have a data frame with normalized values 0..1 in the Sepal.Length column.

Finally it should return

```
    iris
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1      0.8793103         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm strictly interpreting your desire to divide by the max values.

One option:

```
aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length,list(iris$Species),FUN = function(x) x/max(x))
```

and another, using `ddply` from **plyr** (and scales all the columns at once:

```
ddply(iris,.(Species),colwise(function(x){x / max(x)}))
```

And a variant more like @Dwin's `ave` example, that keep the other columns the same, but using `ddply`:

```
ddply(iris,.(Species),transform,Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length / max(Sepal.Length))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the values within each group to range between 0 and 1 (see my answer).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yeah, that's what my code does. Have you run it?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Well, the OP wrote that they specifically wanted to divide by the max value. So that's what I did.

Comment: I agree it's a bit unclear. I was going off the bit where they said they wanted "normalized values 0..1". Guess we'll find out ;)

Comment: OK. Based on the OP's displayed value of Sepal.Length (0.8793103) it looks like you were right. I guess I wanted an interesting question, so read it the way I did.

Comment: colwise seems to apply to all columns. Can i limit it to Sepal.Length?

Comment: @JonasStein Yes, see my edit, or Dwin's answer for another option. Frankly, all of these answers will get you there with minor tweaking.

Comment: i finally used suggestion #(c in this thread. Thanks a lot for the other solutions too. They are very interesting and i learned a lot today, but i could not get all examples running yet. Of course i do not need this for the iris df, but i think an example with a famous df was easier to understand. I think solution #c is the most elegant one. The code is easy to reuse for similar problems and very short and readable.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously there are a ton of ways to do this. I like the syntax of `ave()` (see DWin's answer) or the `data.table` package best:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(iris)
dt[, Sepal.Length:=(Sepal.Length)/max(Sepal.Length), by="Species"]
dt
#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#   1:    0.8793103         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
#   2:    0.8448276         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
#   3:    0.8103448         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
#   4:    0.7931034         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
#   5:    0.8620690         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
# 146:    0.8481013         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
# 147:    0.7974684         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
# 149:    0.7848101         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
# 150:    0.7468354         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica

df <- data.frame(dt) ## It's possible (but not necessary) to coerce back to
                     ## a plain old data.frame
```

Comment: do.call(rbind, lapply(dd, myFun))
Error in scale.default(XX, center = mins, scale = ranges) (from #5) : 
  length of 'scale' must equal the number of columns of 'x'

Answer (score 3):

```
  iris$ratio_to_max <- ave( iris$Sepal.Length, list(iris$Species), 
                                                     FUN= function(x) x/max(x))
#-------------
> str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ratio_to_max: num  0.879 0.845 0.81 0.793 0.862 ...
```

If you wanted to replace the `Sepal.Length` column you could do so, but I generally avoid such destructive practice until I am really sure I got what I wanted. (And even then I feel guilty.) If you wanted this to be in separated list "packets" and throw away the original "Sepal.Length" column, you could use `split`:

```
 spl.iris <- split(iris[-1], iris$Species)
 str(spl.iris)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's way better plyr or data table or even base ways:

```
L1 <- lapply(split(iris[, -5], iris$Species), function(x) apply(x, 2, scale))
L2 <- lapply(seq_along(L1), function(i) {
    data.frame(SPecies=names(L1)[i], L1[[i]])
})
do.call(rbind, L2)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants scaling by dividing by the max, not the SD, so you'd need to add a parameter to your `apply`, I think.

Comment: @Jonas Stein if joran is correct either use his answer or steal the method he uses for scaling and add it to one of these solutions.